# Calculate Route with specific address

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I use this code for calculate distance between two points (km or mi)

```
-(void) CalculateDistance {

    CLLocation *startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self.address.originlatitude doubleValue] longitude:[self.address.originlongitude doubleValue]];

    CLLocation *endlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self.address.destinationlatitude doubleValue] longitude:[self.addresse.destinationlongitude doubleValue]];



    if (self.address.origin && self.address.origin.length > 0) {

        CLLocationDistance calc = [startLocation distanceFromLocation:endlocation];

        double totalDistance = 0.0;
        double totalMileage = 0.0;

        totalDistance = totalDistance + (calc / 1000);
        totalMileage = totalMileage + (calc / 1609);



        if (self.address.distanceKind && ![self.address.distanceKind isEqualToString:@"mi"]) {
            self.distanceTextField.text = [self.numberType stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: totalDistance]];
            self.address.distance = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.distanceTextField.text];
        }else if (self.address.distanceKind &&! [self.address.distanceKind isEqualToString:@"km"]){
            self.distanceTextField.text = [self.numberType stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: totalMileage]];
            self.address.distance = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.distanceTextField.text];

        }


    }
```

The code works fine but calculated distance is incorrect because isn't calculated according a route by car for example.Basically with this code mapView only drawing a straight line and didn't draw a correct destination. Anyone can help me what steps can i do to calculate distance according an route?

Comment: Use `MKDirections` and `MKDirectionsRequest` instead.

Comment: @Larme how can i code this starting from ask? I'm trying see other stackoverflow questions but unsuccessful

Comment: You need to calculate an itinary. There are plenty of questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)DistanceTwoLocation 
{
  **//This is current location take code LocationOne**

 CLLocation *LocationOne = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Location_Manager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:Location_Manager.location.coordinate.longitude];

**//This is current location take code LocationTwo**

 CLLocation * LocationTwo = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[yourLatValue] longitude:[yourLongValue];

 CLLocationDistance DistanceCalc = [LocationOne distanceFromLocation: location];

DistanceCalc = DistanceCalc/1000;

NSLog(@“%@”,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dist:%.2f Km",distance]);
} .
```